# How to create my arbitary output?

Tags: shell-script, centos, command

How can I write a shell script that give me following output:

Today is: Thursday, November 05, 2014
The IP for localhost.localdomain is: 192.168.141.140

Comment: What problem you have with it? Where's the script?

Comment: I've been told to create a script which print the current time, computer host name and IP address(in color). include headers comments in your script. The output has to be Today is: Thursday, November 05, 2014 and the next line it has to say The hostname for localhost.localdomain is: 192.168.141.140.

Answer (score 8):

To get that exact output use:

```
echo "Today is: Thursday, November 05, 2014"
echo "The hostname for localhost.localdomain is: 192.168.141.140"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just run following command:

```
echo "Today  is `date "+%A, %B %d, %Y"`" && echo "The IP for `hostname` is: `hostname -i`"
```

Comment: There is extra spaces, characters missing, the format of the date is dependent on the locale and incorrect in most of the world.

Comment: He tags the CentOS, And it works on all of my PCs or Servers which run Centos ;)

Comment: so many date !! `date "+%A, %B %d, %Y"` will do. Yet the question is still to be asked.

Comment: I run the as your suggestion but it does not show the current date and it is repeating the word hostname and the ip address

Comment: Try again something was missing.